# Creating new registry entries in vc++

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to create new registry entries which copies the certain registry values from  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings. I am successfully able to create the new registry entries but the values and sub key are not copied.I am not able to figure out where I have done the mistake. Please help me out.below is my code:

```
#include<tchar.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<Winreg.h>
#include<WinBase.h >
#include<TlHelp32.h>
#define MAX_PATH 1024
DWORD MigrateProxy;
DWORD ProxyEnable;
DWORD ProxyHTTP11;
LPWSTR AutoConfigURL=0;
LPWSTR ProxyServer=0;
LPWSTR ProxyOverride=0;
void CopyRegistryProxySettings(HKEY hKeyRoot, LPCWSTR Subkey, LPCWSTR ValueKey);
bool CreateNewRegistry(HKEY hKeyRoot);


void main()
{
bool bStatusFlag = false,bReadFlag=false,bWriteFlag=false;
LPCWSTR lpSubKey =  L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings";
LPCWSTR lpValueName = L"AutoConfigURL";
CopyRegistryProxySettings(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, lpSubKey,lpValueName);
bStatusFlag = CreateNewRegistry(HKEY_CURRENT_USER);
//bWriteFlag = RestoreOlderRegistry()


getch();
}

void CopyRegistryProxySettings(HKEY hKeyRoot, LPCWSTR Subkey, LPCWSTR ValueKey)
{
HKEY hKey = NULL;
wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH];
DWORD dwBufLen;
DWORD dwValue = 0;
DWORD dwDataSize = sizeof(DWORD);
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof buffer);
dwBufLen = MAX_PATH;

if ( ERROR_SUCCESS == RegOpenKeyEx(hKeyRoot, Subkey, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS , &hKey))
{

    if(ERROR_SUCCESS == RegQueryValueEx(hKey,L"AutoConfigURL",NULL,NULL,(BYTE*)buffer,&dwBufLen))
    {
        AutoConfigURL = buffer;
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof buffer);

    }
    if(ERROR_SUCCESS == RegQueryValueEx(hKey,L"ProxyServer",NULL,NULL,(BYTE*)buffer,&dwBufLen))
    {
        ProxyServer = buffer;
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof buffer);
    }
    if(ERROR_SUCCESS == RegQueryValueEx(hKey,L"ProxyOverride",NULL,NULL,(BYTE*)buffer,&dwBufLen))
    {
        ProxyOverride = buffer;
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof buffer);
    }
    if(ERROR_SUCCESS == RegQueryValueEx(hKey,L"MigrateProxy",NULL,NULL,(LPBYTE)&dwValue,&dwDataSize))
    {
        MigrateProxy = dwValue;

    }
    if(ERROR_SUCCESS == RegQueryValueEx(hKey,L"ProxyEnable",NULL,NULL,(LPBYTE)&dwValue,&dwDataSize))
    {
        ProxyEnable = dwValue;

    }

    if(ERROR_SUCCESS == RegQueryValueEx(hKey,L"ProxyHttp1.1",NULL,NULL,(LPBYTE)&dwValue,&dwDataSize))
    {
        ProxyHTTP11 = dwValue;

    }


}

}

bool CreateNewRegistry(HKEY hKeyRoot)
{   
HKEY    hKey;
if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\NewSettings\\Internet Settings",  NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hKey, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
 RegSetValueEx(hKey, L"AutoConfigURL", NULL,REG_SZ,(BYTE*)AutoConfigURL, (DWORD)((lstrlen(AutoConfigURL)+1)*sizeof(TCHAR)));
 RegSetValueEx(hKey, L"ProxyServer", NULL,REG_SZ,(BYTE*)ProxyServer, (DWORD)((lstrlen(ProxyServer)+1)*sizeof(TCHAR)));
 RegSetValueEx(hKey, L"ProxyOverride", NULL,REG_SZ,(BYTE*)ProxyOverride, (DWORD)((lstrlen(ProxyOverride)+1)*sizeof(TCHAR)));
 RegSetValueEx(hKey, L"MigrateProxy", NULL,REG_DWORD,(BYTE*)MigrateProxy, (DWORD)sizeof(MigrateProxy));
 RegSetValueEx(hKey, L"ProxyEnable", NULL,REG_DWORD,(BYTE*)ProxyEnable, (DWORD)sizeof(ProxyEnable));
 RegSetValueEx(hKey, L"ProxyHTTP1.1", NULL, REG_DWORD,(BYTE*)ProxyHTTP11, (DWORD)sizeof(ProxyHTTP11));

}

return 1;
}
```

Comment: `AutoConfigURL = buffer; memset(buffer, 0, sizeof buffer);` You make `AutoConfigURL` point to the same memory block that `buffer` already points to - then zero out said memory block. Any data that might have been read by `RegQueryValueEx` is wiped clean. At the end, you have `AutoConfigURL`, `ProxyServer` and `ProxyOverride` all equal to each other and to `buffer`, all pointing to the same block of zeros.

Comment: Also, in `RegSetValueEx` calls, make it `(BYTE*)&MigrateProxy` (and similarly for other `REG_DWORD` values; note the ampersand). It's surprising your program doesn't crash in those calls.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thank you the inputs provided by you really helped I corrected for REG_SZ but not able to do for the REG_DWORD.

Comment: What do you mean, "not able"? What's stopping you?

Comment: Thanks a lot the issue is solved. I was missing & in CreateNewRegistry method in below lines
RegSetValueEx(hKey, L"MigrateProxy", NULL,REG_DWORD(BYTE*)MigrateProxy, (DWORD)sizeof(MigrateProxy));

Comment: Not checking for errors is the first thing to deal with